# How to transfer a list of buffers over a network

Tags: java, networking

I have a Java network application running two threads, one for capturing, encoding, and sending audio and one for receiving, decoding, and playing audio. The method I am using to encode the audio returns a `List<ByteBuffer>`. The decode method I want to use takes a `List<ByteBuffer>` as an argument, so I need to be able to reconstruct the list after sending the data across the network.

The problem that I am having is that I can't figure out how to properly send all of the data across the network without it becoming corrupted. I believe I'm limited by my knowledge of network programming so I'm reaching out for help. I've experimented with a few different approaches (DatagramSockets/Packets, streams, SocketChannels, etc) but I haven't been able to successfully achieve my goal. There are no requirements on what network transmit protocol I need to use so any setup is fine. How can I send my list of buffers over the network so that I can reconstruct it in the receiving thread?

Comment: What is the code of your last attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`GatheringByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer[], ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/GatheringByteChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer:A-int-int-), which is implemented by `SocketChannel`, `DatagramSocketChannel`, and `FileChannel`:

```
ByteBuffer[] bbs = list.toArray(new ByteBuffer[0]);
for (ByteBuffer bb : bbs)
    bb.flip(); // assuming this hasn't already been done
long count = channel.write(bbs);
for (ByteBuffer bb : bbs)
    bb.compact();
```

At this point some or all of the `ByteBuffers` should be empty, ideally all. If they aren't, you must be in non-blocking mode, so select on the channel for `OP_WRITE` and repeat the above when you get it.

**BUT** you won't be able to reconstruct exactly this list at the receiver. The data will be sent as a stream. Even if you used UDP, the `write()` would constitute a single datagram, probably oversized.